# How to use group capturing for selecting words at the end of the line?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having a hard time using group capturing. I have the following text:

```
class Rename < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :users, :vendors
    rename_table :places, :venues
  end
end
```

In this case, I need to extract **vendors** and **venues**.

I'm trying to use something like `/rename_table.*([]+)$/`, but to no avail.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
▶ text.scan(/rename_table.+:(\w+)\s*$/).flatten
#⇒ [
#  [0] "vendors",
#  [1] "venues"
# ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for you:

```
/rename_table.+:(\S+)/g
```

It will store the last word prefixed with `:` form lines containing `rename_table` (`vendors`, `venues`) in match group `$1`.

[Try it online](https://www.regex101.com/r/dB4hD9/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(rename_table.*\,.*\:)(.*)/g
```

match group $1

you can test it here https://regex101.com/r/pN9bO4/1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regexes:

```
str = %q{
class Rename < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :users, :vendors
    rename_table :places, :venues
  end
end
}

str.each_line do |line|
  puts line.split[-1] if line.lstrip.start_with? 'rename_table'
end

--output:--
:vendors
:venues
```

In any case, the group in your regex is `([]+)`.  Brackets are special regex characters and they represent a *character class*, in which you specify the characters that you want to match, e.g. `[xyz]`.  That character class will match one character that is either an `x` or a `y` or a `z`.  In your case, the character class is empty, which produces an error in ruby 2.2:

> empty char-class: /rename_table.*([]+)$/

Essentially, ruby is saying, `Wtf??! You specified a character class with no characters.  Are you really trying to say, I want to match one character that is in the character class consisting of no characters?.  I don't think so! Error! Error! Error!`

Comment: I think OP wants `vendors` and `venues` which are not prefixed with `:`

Comment: `puts line.split[-1][1..-1]`